# WP Query: Filter Products by Pool IDs

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a WooCommerce shop for a customer. The shop data (products, product categories, customers) is imported to the shop via the WooCommerce API.

Some products should only be visible for certain customers. That's why the ERP system provides "product pools" for all products and customers. These product pools are stored as an array in a meta field. The arrays are stored as serialized data in the database.

Every customer can be assigned to multiple product pools, also every product can be assigned to multiple product pools.

I tried to use the `pre_get_posts` hook, to manipulate the product query, depending on the current user's product pools, but the query doesn't show any results.

That's my code:

```
if ( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() && is_shop() ) {

            if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

                $user_id = get_current_user_id();
                $user_product_pools = explode(',',get_user_meta($user_id,'customer_product_pools', true));

                // Check whether the meta field exists in the request array
                if ($meta_value = $query->get('meta_query')) {
                    // Add our condition for the meta field
                    $meta_value[] = [
                        'key'     => '_dpwc_anq_product_pools',
                        'value'   => $user_product_pools,
                        'compare' => 'IN',
                    ];

                    // Update the meta-query array
                    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_value);
                } else {
                    // If the meta-query array does not yet exist, create it
                    $query->set('meta_query', [
                        [
                            'key'     => '_dpwc_anq_product_pools',
                            'value'   => $user_product_pools,
                            'compare' => 'IN',
                        ],
                    ]);
                }


            }

        }
```

This doesn't work. I think the issue is, that I try to compare to arrays with my meta query. Is there any way to archive this? Do I have to change the way I am storeing the pool data? Would it be better to save all the product pools to seperate meta fields?

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: _"I tried to use the woocommerce_process_product_meta hook, to manipulate the product query"_ - isn't that hook called when products get _saved_, from the admin backend ...? I don't think it has anything to do with the actual product queries. If you want to manipulate what products get shown to your website users in the frontend, then that would much rather be a job for the `woocommerce_product_query` hook.

Comment: Sorry, i copied the wrong hook. I use the `pre_get_posts` hook, but it doesn't work.

Comment: _"These product pools are stored as an array in a meta field."_ - so that means what exactly - numeric IDs, pool "names", ...? _"The arrays are stored as serialized data in the database."_ - really rather bad for _searching_ in. Not sure if the use of the `IN` operator makes any sense to begin with in that kind of scenario. (With `'value' => [1, 5, 7]` and a field that contains _either_ 1, 5 or 7, it would make sense. That you can get any proper match if the stored value is a serialized PHP array - I doubt it.)

Comment: For a product meta query, you can use `woocommerce_product_query_meta_query` like in [those threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_product_query_meta_query)

Comment: @CBroe the values are "names" (strings). Since the pools are imported via the WooCommerce API, they are saved as array. Wordpress converts them to serialized data, as far as I know. When I try to use single integer values for the saved product pool, my query works. But I need to be able to save multiple pools for each product.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I don't think that the hook is the problem. `pre_get_posts` should work

Comment: PHP's `serialize` format is real bad to search in. The array `['foo', 'foobar', 'baz']` serialized, gives `a:3:{i:0;s:3:"foo";i:1;s:6:"foobar";i:2;s:3:"baz";}` So to see if `foo` was one of the values, you would need to compare with `LIKE '%"foo"%'` - the double quotes need to be included, because with just `%foo` the `s:6:"foobar"` part would also give a match, even if `foo` wasn't actually present. And since you want to compare against not just _one_ pool, but the user can have multiple, you would need to create the appropriate amount of individual `LIKE ...` conditions, all joined via OR.

Comment: Would probably make more sense, to use a custom taxonomy for this. There should be a way to import & set these pools as taxonomy terms instead, when you import your data. And then you could use a tax_query that gets `terms` (the ones the user has set) passed as an array - of either term IDs, or term slugs.

Comment: Hm yeah I already thought about that in the meantime. I tried it like this: `value' => sprintf(':"%s";', $pool)` combined with 'OR'. When importing/saving the product data, I also make sure, that all values are strings. So this should work - I already tested it.

But you are correct - a solution with a custom taxonomy would probably be better.